# I filed a bug report and now its expired. What do I do now?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I [filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/743832) a bug report.  Eventually I was asked to test the new version.  I was slow in responding.  Now the bug report is expired.  It's still a problem.  Do I just file a new bug report, or is there something else I should do?

Comment: where did you report that bug?

Comment: I reported the bug in launchpad. ( Bug #743832 ).  The bug expired because I didn't respond in time.

Comment: I found your bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/743832. This answers my question: "What happens to expired bug reports? Are they deleted or do they stick around for later viewing?" A: they stick around for later viewing. Good!

Answer (score 6):

I don't see a reason to report a new bug.

As described in [that bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/743832), you should perform further tests, post the results and then you can change its status. I suggest you use `New` if the bug persists or `Invalid` if it has been fixed in new Ubuntu release.